# Bit check for validation

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

How to check whether value is set or not

```
if (A)    Indicator |= 0x10;
if (B)    Indicator |= 0x04;
if(Indicator ) ??
```

Here inside if I want to check whether Indicator have value `0x10` or not, Some case Indicator wil have value `0x10` and `0x04`. I need to check `0x10` is ther eor not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if `(Indicator & 0x10)` is equal to `0x10` or else. If `0x10` then that bit (or bits) is (are) not set if non-zero then that bit is set. This is because the `&` will and each bit of the variable, therefore ANDing with `0x10` (or any other integer say `MASK`) means iff `Indicator` has a `1` in each location of that ANDed integer (`MASK`), the result will be the same as the ANDed integer (`MASK`).

Comment: `Indicator & 0x10` will never be equal to `0x1`.

Comment: Corrected again, overlooked last time.

Comment: The usual rules: `set( unsigned& v, unsigned m ) { v |= m; } unset( unsigned& v, unsigned m ) { v &= ~m; } test( unsigned v, unsigned m) { return (v & m) != 0; }`

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a bit field rather than rely on magic numbers:-

```
struct Indicator
{
  unsigned int A_Set : 1;
  unsigned int B_Set : 1;
}

Indicator indicator;

if (A) indicator.A_Set = true;
if (B) indicator.B_Set = true;

if (indicator.A_Set)
{
  ...
}
```

It's also much easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: Why not bool A_Set : 1  in the struct?

Comment: bool only works in c++ and the question is tagged c++ and c, unsigned int is more portable. But bool would be OK if it was just c++.

Answer (score 1):

You should do :

```
if ( Indicator & 0x10 ) // if zero, the bit is not set if non-zero, the bit is set
```

You should read this : http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Example :

```
(Indicator)    00100     // 0x04
 AND         & 10000     // 0x10
--------------------------------
             = 00000     // the bit is not set


(Indicator)    10000     // 0x10
 AND         & 10000     // 0x10
--------------------------------
             = 10000     // the bit is set


(Indicator)    10100     // 0x14
 AND         & 10000     // 0x10
--------------------------------
             = 10000     // the bit is set
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Indicator & 0x10) ; // A was true
if (Indicator & 0x04) ; // B was true
```

Note that because your two values here are single bits, you don't also need to test for identity.

For multiple-bit values, you may need it though:

```
if (Indicator & 0x14) ; // at least one, and possibly both, of A and B were true
if ((Indicator & 0x14) == 0x14) ; // both A and B were true
```

And of course:

```
if (Indicator == 0x10) ; // exactly A (ie, A but not B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the & operator to find if the bit is set or not.

If the bit is set, result will be true else false.

```
(Indicator & 0x10)
```

Comment: The expression you give will never have a value of `true` or `false`, since it has type `unsigned`.  It should be `(Indicator & 0x10) != 0`.